# Generate matrix given the covariance structure of rows and columns

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, statistics

I have to generate m x n matrix, given two covariance matrices:

1. m x m row covariance matrix (defines the covariance between the rows of the matrix to be generated)
2. n x n column covariance matrix (defines the covariance between the columns of the matrix to be generated)

How can this be implemented in Python?

Edit:
Here is what I have been doing so far:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.linalg.cholesky(row_covariance_matrix)    
B = np.linalg.cholesky(column_covariance_matrix)    
z = np.random.normal(size = (A.shape[0], B.shape[0]))    
C  = A @ z @ B    

# The matrix C should have row covariance A and column covariance B. 
# However, that is not the case and the row covariance of C is way off.
```

Comment: Matrices can be implemented in Python using [numpy arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). Read the documentation and have a go yourself.  If necessary do some tutorials. If you cannot get your code working, post it here.

Comment: @Bill I am aware of how to generate matrices. However, the question I have is about generating a matrix with a particular covariance structure between the rows and the columns of the matrix.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused because you said "how can this be implemented in Python". If you are asking how to compute a covariance matrix, that is a mathematical or statistics question which might be better posted on the [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) stack exchange.

Comment: @martineau Edited

Comment: It's kind of unclear what is the bigger picture here. What does the m by n matrix represent? What are you going to do with it?

Comment: @RobertDodier I am generating new data based on some given data. So, I have some matrix that has a certain column covariance structure and certain row covariance structure. I now want the new data (the m x n matrix) to have the same row covariance and column covariance structure as the existing data.

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting question. I feel like it might not be possible to arrange for the matrix to have a specific row covariance and specific column covariance at the same time. You might take up this general question on stats.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com.